# NSTimer inside custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, class, swift, nstimer, custom-cell

I'm activating a function in my custom cell class from a viewController. The custom cell class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var counter = 10

    class func timerStarted(){
        var timer = NSTimer()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    class func update(){

        let cell = TableViewCell()
        var count = cell.counter
        count = --count
        println(counter)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the variable counter does not change, so 9 is printed every interval. How do I make it so that it changes value every time and counts down?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using a long press gesture recognizer to trigger the function, which is the reason I can't just trigger it using a didSelectRowAtIndexPath-function. My code for the long press looks like this:

```
func longPressActive(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tv)
        if let indexPath = self.tv.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {
            TableViewCell.timerStarted()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to replace `let cell = TableViewCell()` with `let cell = self`

Comment: @gabbler I did that but now when I type in cell.counter it says "TableViewCell.type" does not have a member named 'counter'.

Comment: I've got a solution for you, remove the class specifier before func and change update function like this:`counter = counter - 1 println(counter)
`

Comment: @gabbler I can't remove the class specifier, because then the NSTimer can't find the function and I get an runtime error.

Comment: How did you call `timerStarted`?

Comment: It seems rather arbitrary that you've used a `UITableViewCell` subclass here; these two `class` functions do not interact at all with the class and could just as easily be global. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @gabbler Yes, timerStarted is being called from another VC. The error when I remove the class before func says: "[customTableView.TableViewCell update]: unrecognized selector sent to class".

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm trying to start a countdown when a cell has been tapped; in a snapchat-like manner. But if you have a better solution for solving this I'm more open for other solutions.

Comment: When you click the cell, you know the cell object right? just call `cell.timerStarted()`.

Comment: If you want to start a countdown when an instance is tapped, don't use `class func`; just use `func` **for both**. Your `NSTimer` can't find the instance `func` because you're starting it with a `class` `self` target.

Comment: Okay. But then I get a problem when trying to activate this function from another class; which is a question I've asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943566/setting-off-a-function-in-another-class/27943733#27943733

Comment: The problem here is that you are creating a new class instance every time. So it reallocates a new `counter = 10` every time that function is called and then decrements it (although I think you have a typo in your question as you never actually decrement `counter` you are decrementing `count` then reassigning it to itself which is absolutely redundant). Your whole class is super confusing.

Comment: @gabbler Yes, please take a look at the question I referred to above, that's where the problem has its root.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are using `class` (static) methods but an `instance` variable. So your static method is allocating an instance (Every time) and then decrementing that instance variable. When the method completes, it dumps that instance destroying your newly decremented value (and its related object). You either need to make the variable class related or make your object instancable.

Comment: @frank21, show me where you are calling the `timerStarted()` method and I may be able to give you a better answer. Just do not really have enough info to give you proper advice/a solution. I have a feeling you really do not want to be using static methods. (i.e. I believe the advice you got from your previous question is not really great).

Comment: @Firo I know, but there's no typo in the question; isn't the problem that the 'count' variable gets its value from the global 'counter', so for this issue to go away, the 'counter' needs to change its value every time the 'update'-function is called?

Comment: I have added the code as an answer.

Comment: @frank21, but every single time the `update()` method is called it is recreating your `counter` variable. `counter` is not really "global" in the sense that it is attached to an instance of its object. Every single time that object is created it creates an entirely new `counter` so if you have 100 cells you have a 100 `counters`. Gabbler's answer may be what you are after. That is where I was heading, but I was seeking for more info before posting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so your problem is that you are calling a class method on the TableView class rather than an instance function. You want to get a handle on an actual cell instance, not just the class. So first, your TableCell class with the proper signatures (i.e. remove the `class` prefix):

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var counter = 10

    // No longer class functions! :)
    func timerStarted(){
        var timer = NSTimer()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        // Update counter
        counter-- // <-- performs the actual decrement for you
        println(counter)
    }
}
```

Then just update your long press to activate the timer on an actual cell, not just the cell's class:

```
func longPressActive(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tv)
        if let indexPath = self.tv.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point) {
            // Check to make sure it is the correct subclass
            if let cell = self.tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
                // Starting the timer on the actual cell, not just the cell class
                cell.timerStarted();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I want to make a comment about your `timerStarted()` function. You first create a new timer and assign it to `timer` and then you create a second timer and assign that to `timer` as well, redundant. Also, since you are not saving the timer outside that method there is no need to create a variable (to keep your same functionality). So the function could be:

```
func timerStarted(){
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

But there is a good chance you will want to cancel this at some point, so I would probably store it as an instance variable:

```
private var timer: NSTimer

func timerStarted(){
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is definitely what I'm going for. But the code you provided says 'UITableViewCell' does not have a member named timerStarted? I have removed the class in front of the func in my custom cell class so I can't understand why?

Comment: It is because when you do `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it gives you a `UITableViewCell` not a `TableViewCell`. So just do a forced cast (or an `if-statement`. I will update my answer in one minute.

Comment: Ah yeah, I totally forgot that, thank you so much for your time and this answer and your comments really gave me a better understanding too :)

Comment: @frank21, Yeah, no problem. Check my edit/update and especially my bottom comments about your `timerStarted()` function. I totally understand how confusing the `instance` and `class`/`static` stuff can be. We have all been there. You'll have an ah-hah moment and it will click! Just give it time and keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.timerStarted()
}
```

For your tableview cell class:

```
func timerStarted(){
    var timer = NSTimer()

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update(){
    counter = counter - 1
    println(counter)
}
```

Comment: See my edited question above, I should have been more specific on how the method was called.

Comment: You have got the `indexPath`, you can get the cell from the tableView using the `indexPath`, right?