# fatal error: Index out of range on second cell deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my custom cell I have a timer. When the count down reach 0, I call my delegate method and the cell is automatically deleted. 
The problem is that when the second cell reach 0, my app crashes with the error `fatal error: Index out of range`.

In my custom cell I setup my data:

```
protocol MyDelegateName {
func removeOfferExpired(offerId: String, indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  var offer:Offers?
  var cellIndexPath:IndexPath?
  var delegate:MyDelegateName?


  func setupData(offer:Offers, indexPath:IndexPath){
    self.offer = offer
    self.cellIndexPath = indexPath 
    //...other code not relevant 
  }

//When the time reach zero I call the following method 

func updateTime() {
    if timeLeft > 0 {
        timeLeft = endTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
        offerExpiresLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        offerExpiresLabel.text = timeLeft.hmmss
    }else {
        offerExpiresLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        offerExpiresLabel.text = "Offer Expired"
        timer.invalidate()
        self.delegate?.removeOfferExpired(offerId: (self.offer?.offer_id!)!, indexPath: self.cellIndexPath!)
    }
}
```

In my `ViewController` I setup my cell data inside cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let offer = offers[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.setupData(offer: offer, indexPath:  indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Then inside `func removeOfferExpired(offerId: String, indexPath: IndexPath)` I have tried to use:

```
1. self.offers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
   self.tableView.reloadData()

2. self.offers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
   self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
   self.tableView.reloadData()

3. //and even try to "wrap" it inside begin/end updates
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   self.offers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
   self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
   tableView.endUpdates()
```

it always crashes the second times. I understand that the indexPath I assign to the cell in `setupData` is not the same after the first cell is deleted but I thought `reloadData` was the way to go to update the indexPath in the remaining cells.

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to stop timer if cell was reloaded? 
You should move timer/removing logic outside cells, for example create model object, containing your list and delegating items removing to controller.

Comment: @vojer Thanks but I don't think the crash has anything to do with the timer.

Comment: If old timer fires, delegate could receive call from cell, which is not on screen anymore.

Comment: @vojer in `invalidate()` the timer in `updateTime()` when the offer expires. isn't that enough ?

Comment: Suppose, one of your cell timer isn't expired and table view is reloaded. It's not guaranteed that this cell will be on screen after rows are removed and table is reload. The main problem, that you store timer in reusable cells objects. Make model with static objects with timer list.

Comment: Your problem is that when a cell's item is deleted from the array, the stored indices in the cells after that index are incorrect, since the array is now smaller. Don't store indices in cells.  As @minhazur said, have a timer tick in your view controller and the remove any expired cells by comparing the expiration time as required.

Comment: I understand others use the timer inside the cell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946823/nstimer-inside-custom-tableviewcell

Comment: Ok, I will look at other ways to do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can have the cell run the timer, but you need to pass the `Offers` instance to your delegate method so that your view controller can determine the array index rather than having the cell itself track the index. You also need to handle invalidating the timer in the case where the cell is reused.  Generally you would design your cell to be as lightweight as possible and have no knowledge of the data model

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, but, as you guys said, I think I need to change the way I approached this. Especially if there are several cells. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary issue is that fact that you tell a cell its index path and your cell then passes that index path to its delegate. But a cell's index path isn't stable. It changes as other rows are added, removed, or moved.

The method of your cell protocol should pass itself (the cell) as a parameter, not an index path. Then the delegate can query the table view to find the cell's up-to-date index path and perform the row deletion based on that up-to-date index path.

Comment: got it! I will try that. Do you think that having the timer in the cell will be a problem  when I scroll 10-15 offers and the cells are not visible? Will the label display the right countdown?

Comment: As long as your custom cell properly invalidates its timer in the `prepareForReuse` method and properly resets itself in the `setupData` method, you should be fine. Having the timer in the cell seems to be the proper approach, at least based on what little code you've posted.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that immediately.

Comment: Awesome! It works like a charm now! I don't know what I was thinking!

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy said, what I was doing it was completely wrong. This is what I did based on his answer:

```
func updateTime() {
    if timeLeft > 0 {
        timeLeft = endTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
        offerExpiresLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        offerExpiresLabel.text = timeLeft.hmmss
    }else {
        offerExpiresLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        offerExpiresLabel.text = "Offer Expired"
        timer.invalidate()
        // when the time reach zero I passed self to the delegate instead of the indexPath
        self.delegate?.removeOfferExpired(offerId: (self.offer?.offer_id!)!, cell: self as UITableViewCell)
    }
}

protocol MyDelegateName {
  func removeOfferExpired(offerId: String, cell: UITableViewCell) // delegate method now passes the cell instead of the index
}

func removeOfferExpired(offerId: String, cell: UITableViewCell) {
    // and then I get the index path from the cell 
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    self.offers.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: Your handling of optionals is going to crash. You need to safely deal with `indexPath` being `nil` in your `removeOffsetExpired` method. And every other use of `!` in your code is a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: You are right. I usually check if something is nil before unwrap it. I will fix it. Thanks a lot.